# Email-to-case not working

Tags: lightning

Enabled email-to-case, generated the long salesforce email and verified but I sent a case to the long email and it’s not working.

Comment: 1. From Setup, enter Email-to-Case in the Quick Find box, then select Email-to-Case.
Click Edit.
2. Select Enable Email-to-Case, and click Save.
3. Select Enable On-Demand Service and click Save. This setting allows Salesforce to process your incoming emails.

Comment: have you enabled the " Enable On-Demand Service" setting in the email to case setting? If not please enable and check

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the " **Enable On-Demand Service**" setting in the email to case setting was enabled or not. If not please enable and check.

If you enabled the **Enable On-Demand Service** in the email to case settings then refer the help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324022&type=1) to troubleshoot the issue.